# Designing with AC'97 - why does it not have a (FIFO) buffer?

Tags: audio, design, interface, microblaze, fifo

The AC'97 codec seems to dominate the world of digital audio I/O but, what is weird is that it has neither interrupts nor buffers so that it is difficult to interface with a controller, which has other activities. The AC97 demands polling it periodically (44k times per second), checking for the time to communicate a next sample. This is not the usual way of communicating usually. Usually, CPU fills a buffer and is notified when the operation is complete or waits explicitly for the result if it has nothing else to do. Such "batch processing" is more efficient because, at first, sending bursts is more efficient that doing one item a time and, secondly, it reduces context switching n times, which also optimizes the computational resources accordingly. But, you need a FIFO for that. What is good in this, on sample at time, terrible design of AC97 and why does nobody care? I see that Xilinx fixes it with ML507 demo board (I see FIFOs in AC97 controller introduced there) but I have Digilent's V5 Genesys board whose controller does not provide any FIFO. So that Microblaze must communicate one sample every 1/44100 of a second. Is it efficient? How are you supposed to control it?

Comment: In an FPGA you can easily add your own FIFO to the design.

Comment: It was designed 15 years ago. Today these device are so cheap that most motherboards have one or more of them, but in those days a sound card was pretty expensive. The designers chose for a cheap software implemented interface in contrast to an even more expensive DMA hardware. Mind you computer hardware in the '90 was much more expensive than it is today.

Comment: @jippie, How moving HW from one part to the other saves HW resources. Secondly, being an old device does not mean that we should keep using it. The fact that codec lacks controller makes it difficult to use and begs for a question: why to waste designer/HW resources developing custom controller instead of adding it into AC'97. Third, why DMA? FIFO alone makes things much more useful. For instance, UART is also an old device but they tend to have internal buffer that I can fill and be free for a longer time than sending each byte separately. DMA is not necessary here.

Comment: It is cheap, drivers are everywhere. Why add expensive extra hardware to a system if the CPU can do it for you for free? Mind you a consumer grade hardware manufacturer doesn't want to spend a single cent extra if it isn't really necessary.

Comment: Why buffers were added to UARTs if CPU can do the same for free? Because if CPU does stupid thing "for free", it cannot do anything else at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AC-link part of the [AC97](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC%2797) specification defines the five-wire interface between the codec and a controller. This is not just a data interface, but also a timing interface. This distinction may not seem important in a small embedded system with just one codec, but it becomes crucial in a larger system, such as a 96-channel digital mixing console. In this type of system, all of the audio interfaces need to be running at precisely the same sample rate and phase alignment, and the AC-link standard is designed to support that.

As the other answers have hinted, it is the responsibility of the device at the other end of the link — the "controller", which could be a dedicated ASIC, part of an FPGA, or a microcontroller — to manage both the timing of the codecs in the system as needed, as well as the movement of data from one timing domain to another with the use of suitable FIFOs or buffers.

Comment: Ok, this answer explains very well why we need to synchronize every sample. But, at the same time, AC'79 is de-facto standard of consumer electronics, the dominating part of the market, which has nothing to do with multichannel mixing consoles. Though FIFOs can improve bandwidth when crossing domains, I do not think that this is the major issue here. Efficiency is IMO adversely affected by the fact that CPU has to digress all the time from its duties to control the codec. FIFO reduce the frequency of serving AC'97 and move(buf_ptr,len) is more efficient than for each i<len move(buf[i])

Comment: Not really. Most microcontrollers that you would use in this sort of application have hardware support for I2S, which is generally AC97-compatible, including DMA, which means that the CPU involvement should be fairly minimal.

Answer (score 3):

Audio codecs are real time devices.  They expect you to feed them (or read from them) samples on every sample period.  The design of a simple audio codec would be a lot more complex if you moved that responsibility on to them.  Easier for you, harder and more expensive for the codec.

One possible solution would to use a DMA engine/channel.  So put your pcm audio bits in some contiguous location in memory and point the DMA engine at those bits and your AC97 interface.  Make the dma write frequency 44.1K then let it rip.  You can do the opposite to get audio in.

You could make this block yourself too, just having your own fifo made of internal fpga memory.

Here's a AC97 controller core on OpenCores with external dma support http://opencores.org/project,ac97

Comment: Everybody needs a codec that is easier to communicate with. Being realtime does not change this fact. It would be simpler for codec not to exist at all. Do you mean that existing interface allows the flexibility to choose between FIFO and DMA? I could write into FIFO or command the DMA to transfer sample-by-sample at appropriate time. Right?

Comment: I was saying you could DMA at appropriate time to whatever AC97 interface you are using inside the FPGA.  You still need some FPGA logic to convert from your data to the serial stream the AC97 wants.

Comment: The logic to convert data into serial stream that AC97 codec wants is called codec "controller". Obviously, development kit provides one (otherwise, CPU could not proceed at all) but it has no FIFO inside. That is my question actually, why so stupid controller design?

Answer (score 1):

You probably could design the FPGA to contain a MicroBklaze to poll and write data to the AC97 subsystem. However I really would suggest taking a step back and think about where the source data is actually flowing from. In most cases you would want to design a hardware widget, in FPGA logic, to grab the source data flow and feed it to the AC97 subsystem on the fly at the correct rate. If the data rate is right but there may be some spurious variations in the data flow then it would totally make sense to insert FIFO elastic buffers as part of the hardware widget. FPGA's have nice modules for creating FIFOs